# How to reduce a time dataset to a new, 6-hourly averaged dataset in pandas, python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to make a 6-hourly mean of a dataframe in python. Please see the example below.

```
                  time  temperature
0  2020-01-01 04:30:00            2
1  2020-01-01 05:50:00            3
2  2020-01-01 09:30:00            4
3  2020-01-01 11:50:00            6
4  2020-01-01 13:30:00            3
5  2020-01-01 13:55:00            4
6  2020-01-01 20:30:00            1
7  2020-01-01 22:55:00            4
8  2020-01-02 02:30:00            7
9  2020-01-02 02:40:00            8
10 2020-01-02 10:30:00            3
11 2020-01-02 10:40:00            5
12 2020-01-02 14:30:00            2
13 2020-01-02 15:40:00            6
14 2020-01-02 23:30:00            5
15 2020-01-02 23:47:00            1
```

From this example, ideally I would like to get the following new dataframe:

```
                  time  temperature
0  2020-01-01 06:00:00          2.5
1  2020-01-01 12:00:00            5
2  2020-01-01 18:30:00          3.5
3  2020-01-01 00:00:00          2.5
4  2020-01-02 06:00:00          7.5
5  2020-01-02 12:00:00            4
6  2020-01-02 18:00:00            4
7  2020-01-02 00:00:00            3
```

So, when the time says `2020-01-02 18:00:00` that means on the 2nd of January 2020 from 12h to 18h. The code for the example dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

flights = {
        'time': [datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 4:30 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 5:50 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 9:30 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 11:50 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 1:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 1:55 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 8:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 10:55 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 2:30 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 2:40 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 10:30 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 10:40 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 2:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 3:40 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 11:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 11:47 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')],
        'temperature': [2,3,4,6,3,4,1,4,7,8,3,5,2,6,5,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(flights, columns = ['time','temperature'])
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `6H` and `mean`:

```
#if necessary
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df = df.resample('6H', on='time').mean().reset_index()
print (df)
                 time  temperature
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00          2.5
1 2020-01-01 06:00:00          5.0
2 2020-01-01 12:00:00          3.5
3 2020-01-01 18:00:00          2.5
4 2020-01-02 00:00:00          7.5
5 2020-01-02 06:00:00          4.0
6 2020-01-02 12:00:00          4.0
7 2020-01-02 18:00:00          3.0
```